# Flutter Listview freezes while it is loading thumbnail images from video url and my app crashed

Tags: android, listview, flutter, thumbnails

I am trying to get image from video url when my list scroll but when I use of video thumbnail library and call it in my app list freezes and my app crashed this is my code

```
Future _loadMore(context) async {

final directory=Provider.of<DirectoryPath>(context,listen: false);
Provider.of<LoadState>(context).setLoadState(true);
final index= Provider.of<IndexLazyloading>(context);


if(moves.length!=index.oldmove){
  resetlist(context);

}
// Add in an artificial delay


for (var i = index.currentindex; i <= index.currentindex + increment && i<moves.length; i++) {

  File f=new File( "${directory.directory}/${moves[i].videourl.split("/").last.replaceAll("mp4", "png")}");
 if(!f.existsSync())
await getimage("${strings.baseurl}/videos/${moves[i].videourl}",context);
  index.setdata(i);
}
await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
Provider.of<LoadState>(context).setLoadState(false);
index.setcurrentIndex(index.data.length)  ;
index.setoldMove(moves.length);

}
```

and this is my plugin that used

```
Future<Null> getimage(videourl,context)async{
 final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
 video: videourl,
thumbnailPath: Provider.of<DirectoryPath>(context).directory,
imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
maxHeightOrWidth: 0, // the original resolution of the video
quality: 75,
 );
}
```

i try with png but dont work
this is my list that call this function what is problem in this code please help me

```
 LazyLoadScrollView(
    isLoading: loadstate.isload,
    onEndOfPage: () => _loadMore(context),
child: ListView.builder(
itemCount: indexlayze.data.length,
itemBuilder: (context, position) {
return _buildProductItem(context,position);
},
));
```

my list get 10 image thumbnail when reach to end of list but is very slow how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

How about dedicate this job to a NGINX/NodeJS service running on the cloud? Let the App just downloads the thumbnails from it. This is what I did before.

If you really need to generate the thumbnails by App, try couple things:

- Use JPG/PNG instead of WebP because it costs a lot CPU on iOS
- Create a list or stream to queue the requests, display a placeholder thumbnail before it done.
- Priority the queue once ListView stops scrolling.
- Signal the image component once the thumbnail finished, also take next item to call thumbnail

Comment: i dont know how to handle your guide please send me code example for how to create placeholder and queue for images and requests